# ¿Cómo puedo separar una palabra de 4 letras en Javascript? por ejemplo, tengo la palabra Hola y quiero dividirla en "Ho-la"

Tags: javascript, string, metodos

He intento usar los métodos de string slice y split pero no me han funcionado, ¿Hay algún otro método que pueda usar?

Comment: Ho-la. ¿Qué has investigado, qué has intentado y qué problemas y/o errores tienes? Pulsa en [edit] y completa tu pregunta, agregando el código que tienes escrito para resolver este problema. Conviene que des más detalles, por ejemplo, ¿la palabra siempre tendrá 4 letras o podría tener más o menos, etc.

Comment: Hola Rodrigo, bienvenido, puedes usar: **parte1 = palabra.substring( 0, 2 ); parte2 = palabra.substring( 2, 4 );**

Answer (score 3):

esto podría resolver el problema, específicamente para separar cadenas de texto en pares.

```js
let str = "Hola"
let group = str.split("").map((item, iter, actual) => {
    console.log(item, iter, actual);
    if (iter % 2 == 0) {
        return item + (actual[iter + 1] ?? "")
    }
    return ""
}).filter((i) => i.length > 0)

// "Hola" -> ["Ho", "la"]
// "Hello" -> ["He", "ll", "o"]
```

Desconozco si hay una forma más eficiente de hacerlo, pero puedes seguir investigando.

Además, podrías usar `Array.prototype.slice()` para hacer conjuntos de caracteres más grandes.

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer también con [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), usando la expresión regular **`/.{1,n}/g`** donde `n` representa la cantidad de caracteres que quieres por grupo.

Por ejemplo, para agrupar por dos caracteres:

```js
let group="Hola".match(/.{1,2}/g);
console.log(group);
```

Fuente: [Esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18419843/5587982) en la pregunta [*Split a string to groups of 2 chars using split?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18407260/5587982)